# Get month names between two dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I have to get all months names in order between two dates using Ruby. For example, I want to get:

```
['jan','feb','mars']
```

When I make a diff between:

```
1st january and March 15th
```

I also want it to work when the date diff is greater than one year.

Any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to create a list of months between two dates in Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925905/is-it-possible-to-create-a-list-of-months-between-two-dates-in-rails)

Comment: Yes, but solutions didn't work for me...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd go with:

```
d1 = Date.parse('jan 1 2011')
d2 = Date.parse('dec 31 2012')

(d1..d2).map{ |m| m.strftime('%Y%m') }.uniq.map{ |m| Date::ABBR_MONTHNAMES[ Date.strptime(m, '%Y%m').mon ] }
=> ["Jan",
"Feb",
"Mar",
"Apr",
"May",
"Jun",
"Jul",
"Aug",
"Sep",
"Oct",
"Nov",
"Dec",
"Jan",
"Feb",
"Mar",
"Apr",
"May",
"Jun",
"Jul",
"Aug",
"Sep",
"Oct",
"Nov",
"Dec"]
```

or:

```
(d1..d2).map{ |m| m.strftime('%Y%m') }.uniq.map{ |m| Date::ABBR_MONTHNAMES[ m[/\d\d$/ ].to_i ] }
```

which is probably a little faster.

The problem is the year boundary. You have to track years and months, not just the months, otherwise you'll remove all the duplicated month indexes when using `uniq` to remove the days. I went with the `YYYYMM` format, to get the right granularity.

---

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'date'

d1 = Date.parse('jan 1 2011')
d2 = Date.parse('dec 31 2012')

n = 100
Benchmark.bm(8) do |x|
  x.report('strptime') { n.times { (d1..d2).map{ |m| m.strftime('%Y%m') }.uniq.map{ |m| Date::ABBR_MONTHNAMES[ Date.strptime(m, '%Y%m').mon ] } } }
  x.report('regex')    { n.times { (d1..d2).map{ |m| m.strftime('%Y%m') }.uniq.map{ |m| Date::ABBR_MONTHNAMES[ m[/\\d\\d$/ ].to_i           ] } } }
end

              user     system      total        real
strptime  3.060000   0.020000   3.080000 (  3.076614)
regex     2.820000   0.010000   2.830000 (  2.829366)
```

---

EDIT:

Let's make it even more interesting.

I had some code smell that kept bugging me. I didn't like using `Date.strftime` and `Date.strptime`, so I took another run at the problem: Here are two more solutions that are running a lot faster, along with the benchmarks:

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'date'

def regex_months_between(d1, d2)
  d1, d2 = [d1, d2].map{ |d| Date.parse(d) }.minmax

  (d1..d2).map{ |m| m.strftime('%Y%m') }.uniq.map{ |m| Date::ABBR_MONTHNAMES[ m[/\d\d$/ ].to_i ] }
end

def months_between1(d1, d2)
  d1, d2 = [d1, d2].map{ |d| Date.parse(d) }.minmax

  months = (d2.mon - d1.mon) + (d2.year - d1.year) * 12
  month_names = []
  months.times{ |m|
    month_names << Date::ABBR_MONTHNAMES[(d1 >> m).mon]
  }
  month_names << Date::ABBR_MONTHNAMES[d2.mon]
  month_names
end

def months_between2(d1, d2)
  d1, d2 = [d1, d2].map{ |d| Date.parse(d) }.minmax

  months = (d2.mon - d1.mon) + (d2.year - d1.year) * 12
  (d1.mon ... (d1.mon + months)).each_with_object(Date::ABBR_MONTHNAMES[d1.mon, 1]) { |month_offset, month_names_array|
    month_names_array << Date::ABBR_MONTHNAMES[(d1 >> month_offset).mon]
  }
end

puts regex_months_between('jan 1 2011', 'dec 31 2012').join(', ')
puts months_between1('jan 1 2011', 'dec 31 2012').join(', ')
puts months_between2('jan 1 2011', 'dec 31 2012').join(', ')

n = 100
Benchmark.bm(3) do |b|
  b.report('rmb') { n.times { regex_months_between('jan 1 2011', 'dec 31 2012') } }
  b.report('mb1') { n.times { months_between1('jan 1 2011', 'dec 31 2012') } }
  b.report('mb2') { n.times { months_between2('jan 1 2011', 'dec 31 2012') } }
end
```

With output looking like:

```
Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec, Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec
Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec, Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec
Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec, Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec
        user     system      total        real
rmb  2.810000   0.010000   2.820000 (  2.820732)
mb1  0.060000   0.000000   0.060000 (  0.057763)
mb2  0.060000   0.000000   0.060000 (  0.057112)
```

Interesting. "`rmb`" is now running way behind. Pulling it from the tests and bumping up the loops 100x:

```
n = 10_000
Benchmark.bm(3) do |b|
  b.report('mb1') { n.times { months_between1('jan 1 2011', 'dec 31 2012') } }
  b.report('mb2') { n.times { months_between2('jan 1 2011', 'dec 31 2012') } }
end
```

Which gives:

```
        user     system      total        real
mb1  5.570000   0.060000   5.630000 (  5.615789)
mb2  5.570000   0.040000   5.610000 (  5.611323)
```

It's basically a tie between the two new ways of getting the months. Being anal, I'd go with `mb2` because it'd be a little bit faster if I was doing this millions of times, but your mileage might vary.

Comment: @Sebastien, take it look at it now.

Comment: Hey @theTinMan, I know it's been a while, but what do you think of this solution?

`Set.new((date1..date2).map{|date| date.strftime("%b")}).to_a`

Answer (score 4):

So, let's say you have two dates, `d1` and `d2`:

```
> d1 = 2.years.ago
 => Sun, 19 Sep 2010 15:51:18 CDT -05:00 
> d2 = 1.month.ago
 => Sun, 19 Aug 2012 15:51:25 CDT -05:00
```

(In this case, they're ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone objects, but this works just as well with DateTime or what-have-you)

Make an array to contain your output:

```
 m = []
```

Then fill it up with month abbreviations (using `.strftime`) while incrementing the month:

```
 while d1 <= d2.at_end_of_month
   m << d1.strftime('%b')
   d1 = d1 + 1.month
 end
```

And there it is:

```
 > m
 => ["Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using an array.

Something like this should do it:

```
months = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', etc...]
```

Then you can simply iterate from the lower month to the upper to create your list. Or use the objects' indices like so:

```
months[months.index('jan')..months.index('mar')]
```

Comment: You aren't taking years into account.

Answer (score 0):

```
(start_date..end_date).map{|m| m.beginning_of_month}.uniq.map{|m| Date::ABBR_MONTHNAMES[m.month]}
```

Comment: This breaks badly if the span is over a year long. Try "jan 1 2011" to "dec 31 2012".

Comment: @steenslag `.uniq` is in for reason, so why should I leave it out? I DO want to remove all the superfluous days of a month, or?

Comment: @theTinMan Hmmm..I get ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"] That is, what he wants, or?

Comment: @theTinMan i get the same results as your solution, but admittedly you are more than twice as fast

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way i wrote to solve this issue.
This was designed for working with hash data like:
{Sun, 01 Jan 2012=>58, Wed, 01 Feb 2012=>0, Thu, 01 Mar 2012=>0}
but could be easily modified for array data.

See: https://github.com/StephenOTT/add_missing_dates_ruby

But the key piece of code is:

```
def addMissingMonths (datesHash)
    count = 0
    result = {}

    datesHash.keys.each do |x|
        if x != datesHash.keys.last
            (x+1.month).upto(datesHash.keys[count+1]-1.month) do |a|
                result[a.at_beginning_of_month] = 0
            end
        end

        count += 1
    end

    return result.merge!(datesHash)
end
```

The key content to look at is: `(x+1.month).upto(datesHash.keys[count+1]-1.month)`

Answer (score -2):

Convert the dates to Ruby Dates with a Natural Language Date Parser = [the Chronic Gem](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic). Diff the two dates then.